# runtime error '1004' the extract range has a missing or invalid field name

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sheet2.Range("B2:f" & LastTransRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteriaRange:=Sheet2.Range("p2:q3"), copyToRange:=Sheet2.Range("w2:aa2"), Unique:=True
```

i am getting this debug error: i even checked the name manager, field and headername, but didnt find it, anyone helpme out!

Comment: Check and try emptying/removing any data in the Range("w2:aa2")

Comment: You get that error using `AdvancedFilter` when one or more of the cells in the extract range has **# Errors**. For example  `#N/A` , `#DIV/0` etc. Check the range `Sheet2.Range("B2:f" & LastTransRow)` for the **#** error.

Comment: Provide Screenshot please..

Comment: **after running the code, debug error appears and emptynig/romoving data in the range("w2:aa2")**

Comment: how the advancedfilter causing error???if you think so, how it should be solved?

Comment: @Mr.Ali: Go to the sheet which has the data `Sheet2.Range("B2:f" & LastTransRow)` and first manually check if you see any `#N/A` or `#DIV/0` or similar errors?

Comment: @Siddharth: i already checked that error, i did it again, but no error is showing in the data Sheet2.range("B2:f" & lastTransRow)

Comment: May i see your file?

Comment: it seems to be an error in condtionRange .. Like `=IF(...)` OR `='abc'`

Comment: @SiddharthRout: how can i share the file? guide me i'll share it

Comment: wikisend.com or dropbox or onedrive?

Comment: onedrive? tellme plz

Comment: put your file in onedrive and share the link here

Comment: https://damasjewellery-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/personal/muhammadi_damasjewellery_com/Documents/P%26L-1.xlsm?d=wb70ef45cfb5f473d8d838acdcf9f68a3&csf=1&web=1&e=5RSVc2

Comment: when you got it do let me know!

Comment: it is not public. Do this. upload it on www.wikisend.com and then share the link

Comment: @SiddharthRout
http://wikisend.com/download/962510/P&L-1.xlsm

[URL=http://wikisend.com/download/962510/P&L-1.xlsm]P&L-1.xlsm[/URL]

Comment: these are the links

Comment: You have a typo. In Cell F2 you have `Account Type`. Check what you have in `AA2` ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: but got the same... nothing effect in the file... i mean, data removed from filterResults... :(

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: i didn't get any error

Comment: So the error problem is sorted. Now you need to go back and do what you want manually and see if it works. I would recommend deleting this quesiton starting a new question

Comment: Run the Code: No Effect appears iin th report: Even Data from FilterResults disappears:<<<